# How can I calculate overall variance in a heteroskedastic hierachical model?

Tags: variance, multilevel-analysis, heteroscedasticity, hierarchical-bayesian

I have the following model:

$$\theta \sim N(1, 0.1)$$
$$X \sim N(\beta_1\theta + \alpha_1, \beta_2\theta + \alpha_2)$$

Where I can safely assume that $\beta_2\theta + \alpha_2$ is always positive.

How would I calculate the overall variance of samples from $X$, please?

Comment: I think the distribution of X is conditional on theta.

Comment: How can you safely assume $\beta_2 \theta + \alpha_2$ is positive unless $\beta_2 = 0$? If you throw out all the samples where this is not true, then $\theta$ follows a truncated normal distribution.

Comment: @utobi yes agreed, but here I am interested in calculating 'overall' variance $\frac{1}{n} \Sigma^n_{i=1} (X_i - \bar{X})^2$ which I suppose you could regard as summing over many distributions of $X$

Comment: @NiklasvMoers I didn't want to labour this bit of the problem statement, but above I mean that the standard deviation of $\theta$ is 0.1, so negative values of theta are very unlikely given that I will only be drawing 1000s of samples. Then, as my $\beta_2$ and $\alpha_2$ are positive I think I can make this assumption in practice.